# Как вывести разделы первого уровня из инфоблока Каталог. Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Кто знает как вывести разделы первого уровня из инфоблока Каталог. Вот шаблон компонента catalog.section.list.

Отображаются разделы первого уровня, а так же подразделы. Нужно только разделы первого уровня.

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>

<ul class="items-tile">
<?
 $TOP_DEPTH = $arResult["SECTION"]["DEPTH_LEVEL"];
 $CURRENT_DEPTH = $TOP_DEPTH;

 foreach($arResult["SECTIONS"] as $arSection)
 {
  $this->AddEditAction($arSection['ID'], $arSection['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arSection["IBLOCK_ID"], "SECTION_EDIT"));
  $this->AddDeleteAction($arSection['ID'], $arSection['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arSection["IBLOCK_ID"], "SECTION_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BCSL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
  if($CURRENT_DEPTH < $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"])
  {
   echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"]-$TOP_DEPTH),"";
  }
  elseif($CURRENT_DEPTH == $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"])
  {
   echo "";
  }
  else
  {
   while($CURRENT_DEPTH > $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"])
   {
    echo "";
    echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH),"","\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH-1);
    $CURRENT_DEPTH--;
   }
   echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH),"";
  }

  echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"]-$TOP_DEPTH);
  ?>

<li id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arSection['ID']);?>" class="before after ease-out"><div class="pd20">
<div class="h4"><a href="<?=$arSection["SECTION_PAGE_URL"]?>"><?=$arSection["NAME"]?></a></div>
<div class="content text-small mb10"><?=$arSection["DESCRIPTION"]?></div>
</div></li>


<?

  $CURRENT_DEPTH = $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"];
 }

 while($CURRENT_DEPTH > $TOP_DEPTH)
 {
  echo "";
  echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH),"","\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH-1);
  $CURRENT_DEPTH--;
 }
 ?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: `if ($arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1)`? Также https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/catalog/catalog_section_list.php

Comment: Чего то не помагает, либо может не туда размещаю. В документации ничего нет про это.

Comment: Внимательней читайте: __TOP_DEPTH__ - Параметр определяет максимальную глубину отображаемых разделов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение с помощью настроек компонента.
Нажимая на шестеренку, комплексного компонента Каталог.
Поле: Максимальная глубина... значение 1